# Random Display String from a list when clicking ElevatedButton

Tags: arrays, string, flutter, list, random

I would like to display a random string when i click the ElevatedButton.However,the same string still display when i click ElevatedButton. The string will be randomly change only when i restart the app.

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Random List Here
    List<String> countries = [
      "USA",
      "United Kingdom",
      "China",
      "Russia",
      "Brazil"
    ];
    countries.shuffle();
    String country = countries[0];
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("GeeksForGeeks"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      // ignore: avoid_unnecessary_containers
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
                  title: const Text("Shuffle List in Flutter"),
                  content: Text(country),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14),
                        child: const Text("okay"),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
            child: const Text("Show alert Dialog box"),
          ),


        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The same countries name will be displat everytime i click the button

[image]

Restart the app is the only way i can randomly change the country name.

[image]

what i need to add on in order to display random country everytime i click the button?

Comment: on which button you want to shuffle the list?

Comment: Try calling `setState(() {})` right after `Navigator.of(ctx).pop()`

Comment: just try console printing the list or variable on button click, if that gets correctly I have solution for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose an alternative, by using the `dart:math` library and generating the random number from the index.

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Random List Here
    List<String> countries = [
      "USA",
      "United Kingdom",
      "China",
      "Russia",
      "Brazil"
    ];
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("GeeksForGeeks"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              final _random = new Random();
              var country = countries[_random.nextInt(countries.length)];
              showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
                  title: const Text("Shuffle List in Flutter"),
                  content: Text(country),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14),
                        child: const Text("okay"),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
            child: const Text("Show alert Dialog box"),
          ),


        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The general way to `generate random` element from a list.

```
import "dart:math";

var list = ['a','b','c','d','e'];

final _random = new Random();

var element = list[_random.nextInt(list.length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Random().nextInt(max)` to get a random index of the list instead of `shuffle`.

```
              showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
                  title: const Text("Shuffle List in Flutter"),
                  content: Text(countries[Random().nextInt(countries.length)]),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14),
                        child: const Text("okay"),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
```

I hope this helps.